# not sure why my looping function isnt working here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a testimonial section for a website. This is a project I am building as part of my portfolio, it isnt really for a client.

Nonetheless, what I am trying to achieve is for each of these testimonials to appear within its parent div one by one. I have put them in their own seperate divs then used a counter and function to iterate through them appearing individually, however something does not seem to be working (and the console does not seem to be logging any errors).

My code is provided below. Many thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center">

<div class="col-md-12" id="customerreviews">

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 1"</p>

<h4>Rachel Smith<span class="location"> (Manchester)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 2"</p>

<h4>Darren Wise<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 3"</p>

<h4>Arif Akhtar<span class="location"> (Leeds)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 4"</p>

<h4>Jason Hardy<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 5"</p>

<h4>Michelle Rousey<span class="location"> (Birmingham)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 6"</p>

<h4>Jermaine Clarke<span class="location"> (Bristol)</span></h4>

</div>


</div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var testimonials = $(".customercomment");
var testimonialsDiv = $("#customerreviews");

var currentTestimonial = 0;

function switchComments(){
if (currentTestimonial == testimonials.length-1){
currentTestimonial = 0;
}

$(testimonials[currentTestimonial]).fadeIn("fast",function(){
$(testimonials[currentTestimonial]).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
currentTestimonial++;
})
}
```

switchComments();

*EDIT* the code is fading in the first element with class "testimonials", but after it fades out, nothing else appears.

Comment: Where are you calling the function `switchComments()`?

Comment: Also `testimonials[currentTestimonial].fadeIn` is not a thing - maybe you meant `var testimonials = $(".customercomment");` or `$(testimonials[currentTestimonial]).fadeIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jquery when you gain elements.

```js
var testimonials = $(".customercomment");
var testimonialsDiv = $("#customerreviews");

function switchComments(){
  var ix, ixLen;
  
  for(ix = 0, ixLen = testimonials.length; ix < ixLen; ix++){
    $(testimonials[ix]).delay(1000 * ix).fadeIn("slow");
  }
}

switchComments();
```

```css
.customercomment{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center">

<div class="col-md-12" id="customerreviews">

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 1"</p>

<h4>Rachel Smith<span class="location"> (Manchester)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 2"</p>

<h4>Darren Wise<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 3"</p>

<h4>Arif Akhtar<span class="location"> (Leeds)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 4"</p>

<h4>Jason Hardy<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 5"</p>

<h4>Michelle Rousey<span class="location"> (Birmingham)</span></h4>

</div>

<div class="customercomment text-center">

<p>"TEXT 6"</p>

<h4>Jermaine Clarke<span class="location"> (Bristol)</span></h4>

</div>


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: did you check what you have posted? __OP-Required__  **what I am trying to achieve is for each of these testimonials to appear within its parent div one by one**

Comment: Hello guys thanks for your comments. @MuhammadOmerAslam I have ammended my code as moon suggested, and it has at least brought up the first class of testimonials, but when the first one fades out, nothing appears after. I have edited the OP for up to date code in my project.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yeah, I've seen it, and I've edited my code again.

Comment: thats more like it took back my -1

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you for your notice, you got my back..! Haha

Comment: downvoting should be for productive reasons only I see guys downvote for no reason too, and never take it back after a correct solution is provided, anyway, we are all here to help each other. cheers @moon

Comment: Thanks for the help @moon , i really appreciate it! thanks to everyone else who also took out the time to respond!

Comment: This seems to do what the OP asked. But it lacks the flexibility a plain javascript setTimeout() would give. You can't stop/pause the process. Or create an 'infinite' loop without crashing your browser.

Comment: @RMo What do you mean 'lacks the flexibility'? Could you give me more explanation on your thought of 'better way' in that code, please?

Comment: @moon This code iterates over each element once. You can't change that once you start it (as far as I know). With a setTimeout() you could for example clear the timeOut if you hover over the `#customerreviews`-div. And start to fade in the next comment once an user removes his mouse from the `#customerreviews`-div. Hope that somewhat explains what I tried to say.

Comment: @RMo Oh, so you mean, in the prospective of kind of a dynamic action, like hover over DOM elements, my codes above wouldn't be the best one, since it will loop over all the elements in `testimonials` by for-loop?